# A4j buttons don't fire

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam, ajax4jsf

I used richfaces in a JSF project. Now I'm trying the same with Seam.
But I always get the same JavaScript error:

```
Message: Object required
Line: 2791
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/myapp/a4j/g/3_3_1.GA/org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js
```

The s:button tag works

```
 <s:button id="eMail0" value="sButton" action="#{Mailer.sendMail}" />
```

Both of the following lead to the described JavaScript message in IE8 (Firefox shows no response)

```
 <a4j:commandButton id="eMail1" value="cmdButton" action="#{Mailer.sendMail}" />

 <a4j:commandLink id="eMail2" action="#{Mailer.sendMail}">
     <f:param name="email" value="param"/>
     <h:outputText value="eMailLink"/>
 </a4j:commandLink>
```

Any ideas on how I could work around that issue, or is there a known issues with seam 2.2.0?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Seam. I have never seen this javascript error. But I only use Firefox, so perhaps that is the reason...What is the error, apart from the javascript message? The actions isn't executed? Have you enclosed the buttons in `<h:form>`?

Comment: @Shervin Thank you, I tried to put the a4j:commandLink into a non list which wasn't enclosed by h:form. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enclosed the buttons in `<h:form>`?